# Kendo ListBox Keyboard Navigation Bug

Tags: kendo-ui

Go to the [Keyboard Navigation Demo Page](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listbox/keyboard-navigation).

1. Click in the Left Hand list box.
2. `ctrl+shift+right arrow`
3. All the items move to the Right hand box (correct)
4. `ctrl+shift+left arrow`
5. All the items move to the Left hand box (also correct)

Now repeat 1-3 then click in the (now empty) left hand box.
Now try any combination of mouse clicks and keyboard strokes and see if you can get anything to move back to the left hand box.

Comment: This isn't a question. Bug's should be filed to Kendo's support or to https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove or change the condition for forcing the focus

```
$(document).on("keydown.examples", function (e) {
            if (e.altKey && e.keyCode === 87) {
                $("#listbox").data("kendoListBox").focus();
            } else {
            $("#listbox").data("kendoListBox").focus();
            }
        });
```

**Just for test if you put the focus on both conditions** the keyboard navigation will work no matter what. 
Try to find the conditions you require the keyboard actions to be on.